# Why is equality of limits not true?

Tags: calculus, limits

> [image]

I swear $$\lim[f(x) - g(x)] = \lim f(x) - \lim g(x)$$

Also just because I'm so confused now.. This is true right..?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to c}g(x)}$$
only applies when each of the limits exist, **AND** $\lim_{x \to c}g(x) \neq 0$. Observe in your case that $\lim_{x \to c}g(x) = 0$.

Comment: I see, thanks! Based on that this question would also be false, right? http://puu.sh/rCvDS/2d0e6080fd.png

Comment: @HelloMellow Yes.

Comment: Wait wait, the question would be true I mean. Because the question states "It does not exist", so it'd be true since it doesn't exist.

Comment: @HelloMellow, that is a $0/0$ indeterminant form.  For example, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{n}{n} = 1$, even though the denominator (and numerator) limit to zero.

Answer (score 2):

That is only true *if the limits exist*. In your example they do not and it is not.

The limit is actually 2.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that rule. Thank you!